# Persistent Controller Of One App Is Coming in Other App in Google Cast?

Tags: casting, controller, chromecast, persistent

I have two Android applications both using Google Cast Sdk. Persistent Controller of One App is Coming in Another Application. How To Manage this. I don't want other persistent controller to come in my Android Application. Please help.

Comment: Provide a screenshot since I believe you are mistaking with the assumption that it is from other "apps".

Comment: @AliNaddaf. I have two applications.

Comment: Are they using the same App Id?

Comment: Earlier I was using the default reciever id . I have changed the app-id of the chromecast. In new App-Id I am using styled media receiver but sometimes app crashes while video is in queue with new app-id.                                         Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@978e548 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1813dd4[Running, pool size = 17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 1074]
android.app.ActivityThread.main
 Raw Text

Comment: Error Coming(With Launch Mode = singleTop) :Error :
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@978e548 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1813dd4[Running, pool size = 17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 1074] at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.RemoteMediaClient$1.onStatusUpdated(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzza.onStatusUpdated(Unknown Source)